# How to remove base url from layout argument

Tags: layout, magento2.3

I am using layout argument in `path` but it display with base url like

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link"  name="search-mini-text">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Search Products..</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">javascript:void(0)</argument>
                        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">search-mini-text</argument>
                   </arguments>
                </block>
```

When I add this it display like this

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.0/demomage230/javascript:void(0)/" class="search-mini-text">Search Products..</a>
```

Expected result should be

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-mini-text">Search Products..</a>
```

But i woluld like to display `javascript:void(0)` instead.

How can i exclude baseurl in path argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with this

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link"  name="search-mini-text">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Search Products..</argument>
                        <argument name="onclick" xsi:type="string" translate="false">return false</argument>
                        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">search-mini-text</argument>
                   </arguments>
                </block>
```

It will prevent redirecting on click

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix would be instead of putting your JS in the path, you can just use the on click attribute.

But if you really want to pass your JS as a href, you are going to modify the logic of the block. Since the `getHref` method pass the path into `getUrl` which prepends the base url.

You could either create a custom block that extends `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link` and overwrite the `getHref` method with `return $this->getPath()` and then reference that new block in your XML.

Or you could create a after plugin for `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link::getHref` and check if a custom argument exists such as `isPathRelative` if it does then just return `$this->getPath` otherwise return the result from the initial plugin

Comment: Let me try your way.